# Get multiple values from listbox using django

Tags: python, django, listbox

I am trying to get values from a listbox, but I was facing a `MultiValueDictKeyError`. So I tried using get(), but now I am not getting any value from the listbox.

```
<form action="/submission/" method="get" name="Form1"><br>
    <select multiple="multiple" name="Other_users" size="2">
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
    </select>
    <input id="Save" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;" type="submit" value="Save"></form>
```

This is my **views.py**

```
def submission(request):
    ..
    taker = request.GET.get('Other_users','f')
    print taker
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^submission/', submission),
)
```

This code actually prints out `f`. How do I fetch the values `option1` and `option2` and store them in say, an array?

EDIT:

I think I should add that if I remove the `multiple="multiple" size="2"` part (ie create a simple dropdown), I do not face any issue. It is only in the case of listbox

EDIT2:

The problem seems to be that the listbox is not in the `QueryDict` when I do `print request.GET`. Why isn't `request.GET` picking up the listbox?

Comment: Use django forms to handle formdata input. It makes the whole process much easier, evolutive and you're much less likely to get it wrong and introduce huge security holes in your application.

Comment: I will look into django forms, thanks for the suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

Try It:

```
request.GET.getlist('Other_users')
```